# NET Core Web application - System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: .net-core, web-applications, socketexception

So I'm trying to set up a self-signed web application on my computer but are running into this exception whenever the application runs.

**Exception:**

```
    crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

The local host file is set to resolve "cserv.dk" on my ip address, and certificate is added to trusted.

**Program file**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((context,services) => {
            HostConfig.CertPath = context.Configuration["CertPath"]; // From development.json
            HostConfig.CertPassword = context.Configuration["CertPassword"]; // From secrets.json
        }
        
        )
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                var host = Dns.GetHostEntry("cserv.dk");
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(opt =>
                {
                    opt.Listen(host.AddressList[0], 80);
                    opt.Listen(host.AddressList[0], 443, listOpt => {
                        listOpt.UseHttps(HostConfig.CertPath, HostConfig.CertPassword);
                    }); // Listen on HTTPS
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

I did make one mistake. The first time I ran the project, I did so using IIS Express (normal IIS is not installed). From what I can tell, this has somehow screwed things up.
Even with everything closed and or the computer restarted, writing "cserv.dk" in the browser shows a blank page - not an error. It even re-direct to https if called on :80.

I'm assuming its because the 443 port is somehow in use, but afaik it really shouldn't be. Doing a "netstat -ao" doesn't seem to reveal anything.

I've tried deleting any remains of site in IIS Express using ...

```
appcmd.exe list site /xml | appcmd delete site /in
```

No luck, I need help :D

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the cause, VMWare. Removing all processes fixed the issue, I assume its something to do with its NAT feature.

Comment: I disabled Shared VMS from the preferences and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and could solve it by restarting nat:

```
net stop winnat
    
net start winnat
```